# Thread.join() crashing in tkinter in python

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have this thread that needs to be called from the toplevel part in the tkinter app.
But if i am trying to call self.t1.join() as seen below it is crashing the tkinter app(python) . Can you help me out?

```
 class App(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.th1=False   

    ####### Thread function --> Bit_Track ##################
    def Bit_track(self,gud):
      while(self.th1):
          *** some code****
           if(self.th1==False):
             return

    ######## thread starting ##########
    def bit_thread(self,gud,con_win):
       self.t1=threading.Thread(target=self.Bit_track,args=(gud,))
       con_win.insert(INSERT,"Thread started\n")
       self.th1=True
       self.t1.start()

    def Bit_track_stop(self,gud,con_win):
      self.th1=False
      con_win.insert(INSERT,"Thread stopped\n")

      #self.t1.join()
      for i in range(2):
        for j in range(31):
           gud[i][j].set(0)

      #self.t1.join()
      print("hello")
   ###onclosing ####
   def onclosing(self):
      self.t1.join()
      self.th1=False
      return

   def gui2_create(self):
      newWin = Toplevel(self)
  
      bt1=Button(fr3,text="Start",width=10)
      bt2=Button(fr3,text="Stop",width=10)
      bt1.configure(command=ptr(self.bit_thread,chk_bt_n,con_win))
  bt2.configure(command=ptr(self.Bit_track_stop,chk_bt_n,con_win))

       (****Here is the problem starting ****)
      newWin.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.onclosing)


 app = App()
 app.mainloop()
```

As you can see here the bit_thread is starting the thread and onclosing will get activated as soon as the toplevel window is closed.

The error is coming when the self.t1.join() is called in onlcosing the app is freezing. Can you help me out with two thiongs

1. How to close the thread on closing toplevel
2. Is my thread implementation correct and if not can you correct me?

I am trying to implement above code but it is freezing the app. I tried to use join method as well as the make ythe flag as afalser but still the app is freezing.

I need to see the threead closing.

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre]; try to figure out **where** the problem is occuring and **what part** of the code causes it. This is far too much code for an example.

Comment: Can't you just swap `self.th1=False` with `self.t1.join()`?

Comment: I tried it but the app is still crashing

Comment: @user20182755 The app is crashing because the code inside the `while` loop is taking too long. Is there a problem if the code in the `while` loops just stops when you close the `tkinter` window? Do you know why you have .join()` there and is it needed? Do you know what the daemon flag does in threads?

Comment: as it currently stands your only two options are to post the code that's causing the problem or remove threading from the program until you are more familiar with how threads work, the question currently cannot be answered, and you have a bug that you need to fix by yourself.

Comment: Re, "I tried it but the app is still crashing." If the order of the two statements in your `onclosing` method in your example is not the same as in the code that is giving you trouble, then you should fix the example so that it matches the code that you are asking about. Also, fix the text so that it accurately describes the "crash" that frustrates you. You'll get more help solving your problem if you give more help to the people who are trying to understand it for you.

Comment: The indentation isn't format probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onclosing` method tries to `join` the thread *before* it sets the flag that tells the thread to stop.

```py
   def onclosing(self):
      self.t1.join()
      self.th1=False
      return
```

If the thread won't stop until `self.th1 == False`, and if no other method sets `self.th1=False`, then that `join()` call is never going to return.

Have you tried switching the order of those two statements?

```py
   def onclosing(self):
      self.th1=False
      self.t1.join()
      return
```

---

Note: This is exactly the kind of problem that you can solve by [explaining it to the duck.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: First of all, @Thingamabobs already suggested that but OP said that it doesn't work (look at the comments on the question). Second of all, I am not sure if it's allowed to post links to amazon promoting a t-shirt.